# how do i create a php function to echo out mysql data, a function that can be reused?

Tags: php

I need to write a PHP function to echo out MySQL rows as I give it the SQL query I want to be executed as the function argument. I have tried out the following code but it is giving me an undefined index error

```
function runQuery($query) {
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb');
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $resultset[] = $row;
    }       
    if(!empty($resultset))
        return $resultset;
```

the code I am using to call the function is;

```
runQuery(SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id='5')
echo $resultset['name'];
```

this, however, gives me this error, undefined index 'resultset' on line 25. any kind assistance would be appreciated

Comment: You haven't shown us the real code. Your resultset is a multidimensional array.

Comment: Please read about mysqli https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli

Comment: Now after that edit, there is another error in the code as `$conn` is not visible inside the function as it was not created in there

Answer (score 1):

You dont have a `$resultset` in the scope of where you call the function. The function creates one, but that is only visible inside the function.

You will also have to put QUOTES around the query, you are passing a string there so it needs to be quoted.

> Your errors should have generated quite a few error messages, if you were not getting them I have added 4 lines of code you should add while testing code for example if you are testing on a LIVE server with error reporting turned off.

You should also change the function to ensure you always return something

So amend the call to

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

function runQuery($conn, $query) {
    $resultset = [];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $resultset[] = $row;
    }       
    return $resultset;
}


$resultset = runQuery($conn, "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id='5'");


// as result will now be a multidimentional array 
// you will need to loop over that to get each returned row
foreach ( $resultset as $row ) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

> AFTER your edit there is another error

`$conn` is not created inside the function, so will be invisible in the function code unless passed as a parameter to the function (there is another way but lets not get into the bad habit of using global variables)

Answer (score 0):

First, your code is probably vulnerable to SQL Injection. Please take care of that, by using prepared statements for instance.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp
https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

Other than that, you do not assign the return value of your function to a variable. You cannot use the `$resultset` defined in the function scope outside the function, as it is a different scope. Try the following:

```
$resultset = runQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id='5'")
echo $resultset['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I built a similar function recently - here is my code

```
function returnSQL($conn, $nameSql) {
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $nameSql);
 if (!$result) {
 return 0;
 }
while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$data[] = $res;
}
  return $data;
}
```

The connection is setup outside the function and passed in as an argument along with the sql like this...

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $DBName);
  if (!$conn) {
   echo 'Failed to connect to database :- ' . $DBName . '<br>';
   die();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$data = returnSQL($conn, $sql);
```

I'm no expert, but this works for me :)

What I notice from your code is that you are trying to access $resultset outside of the function it is declared in and I think it is not available as a global variable - perhaps it should be something like:

```
$returnValue = runQuery(SQL statement);
// $returnValue is assigned the array returned from runQuery()
echo $returnValue['name'];
```